# About Random Number Generation

Tags: c

I wrote code but when I compile it  it seems like a wrong sums.Can you help me ?

> There are n students that take course and there are five sections for this course write a c program using a function with prototype int random assignment that randomly assigns each student one of the five section and print which students is assigned to which section at the end of the program you should report how many students are in each section. Your function will generate a random number between 1 and 5.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int fun(void){
return 1 +rand()%5;
}
int main(){
int numstu,count,a,sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5;
printf("Enter the number of students:");
scanf("%d",&numstu);
for(count=1;count<=numstu;count++){
    a=fun();
    printf("Student number %d assigned to %d\n",count,a);
    if (a==1)
    sum1=sum1+1;
    if (a==2)
    sum2=sum2+1;
    if (a==3)
    sum3=sum3+1;
    if (a==4)
    sum4=sum4+1;
    if (a==5)
    sum5=sum5+1;
}
printf("The number of student in section 1 is %d",sum1);
printf("The number of student in section 2 is %d",sum2);
printf("The number of student in section 3 is %d",sum3);
printf("The number of student in section 4 is %d",sum4);
printf("The number of student in section 5 is %d",sum5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong in what way?

Comment: You never call `srand()` for starters...

Comment: Please study [ask]

Comment: Have you come across arrays yet?  It's a program that would benefit from  `int sum[5] = { 0 };` and corresponding changes.

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialise any of your variables, nor perform any error checking.

Do this:

```
int numstu = 0, count = 0, a = 0;
int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0, sum5 = 0;
```

and check the result of `scanf`.

*(declarations split up for readability)*